# Adding Locations tool & sublayers in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, arcgis-10.6, error-030024

I run ArcGIS 10.6.1. I am currently doing a network analysis but run into the problem where I can't relate the error I get to what I want to do. My code looks like this:

```
XMLPath="C:\\Work\\TemplateXML"
NetworkDataset="C:\\Work\\GDBTejo.gdb\\PTA" 

arcpy.na.CreateNetworkDatasetFromTemplate(XMLPath, NetworkDataset)
arcpy.na.BuildNetwork(NetworkDataset)
arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaLayer(NetworkDataset, "TransportBus250m", impedance_attribute="Length", travel_from_to="TRAVEL_FROM", default_break_values=250, polygon_type="NO_POLYS", line_type="TRUE_LINES", overlap="NON_OVERLAP", lines_source_fields="LINES_SOURCE_FIELDS")
arcpy.na.AddLocations(in_network_analysis_layer="TransportBus250m", sub_layer="TransportBusLine250m", in_table=NetworkDataset+"\\BusStops", field_mappings="", search_tolerance=250)
arcpy.na.Solve("TransportBus250m")
```

Now I get an error on the AddLocations line, stating:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000192: Invalid value for Sub Layer
Failed to execute (AddLocations).
```

Reading the [Esri website about it](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/add-locations.htm) does not really help me as they say:

> sub_layer=The sublayer of the network analysis layer to which the network analysis objects will be added.

What do I need to change, so that my sub_layer gets accepted?

---

I adapted now my code as suggested by @smiller and it looks now like this:

```
    XMLPath="C:\\Work\\TemplateXML"
    NetworkDataset="C:\\Work\\GDBTejo.gdb\\PTA" 

    arcpy.na.CreateNetworkDatasetFromTemplate(XMLPath, NetworkDataset)
    arcpy.na.BuildNetwork(NetworkDataset)
    outNALayer=arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaLayer(NetworkDataset, "TransportBus250m", impedance_attribute="Length", travel_from_to="TRAVEL_FROM", default_break_values=250, polygon_type="NO_POLYS", line_type="TRUE_LINES", overlap="NON_OVERLAP", lines_source_fields="LINES_SOURCE_FIELDS")
    outNALayer = outNALayer.getOutput(0)
    subLayerNames = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(outNALayer)
    facilitiesLayerName = subLayerNames["Facilities"]
    arcpy.na.AddLocations(in_network_analysis_layer="TransportBus250m", sub_layer=facilitiesLayerName, in_table=NetworkDataset+"\\BusStops", field_mappings="", search_tolerance=250)
    arcpy.na.Solve("TransportBus250m")
```

The script now gives the error message:
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 030024: Solve returned a failure.
No edges were traversed.
Failed to execute (Solve).

---

Problem solved! The XML-template had a wrong line in it. Instead of declaring the road network and the facilities as part of the network dataset, one only needs to declare the road network as part of the network dataset. The facilities are then just added as locations to make it work.

Comment: Use Facilities as the sublayer when working with ServiceArea Analysis. Check out Example 3 here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/make-service-area-layer.htm

Comment: What do you get from `print(arcpy.GetMessages()) after adding locations?

Comment: I got this: Executing: AddLocations TransportBus250m Facilities C:\Work\GDBTejo.gdb\PTA\BusStops "" "250 Unknown" # "Road_Network SHAPE;BusStops SHAPE;PublicTransportNetworkBus_Junctions NONE" MATCH_TO_CLOSEST APPEND NO_SNAP "5 Meters" INCLUDE "Road_Network #;BusStops #;PublicTransportNetworkBus_Junctions #"
Start Time: Wed May 15 18:14:01 2019
16 features located out of 16.
Succeeded at Wed May 15 18:14:01 2019 (Elapsed Time: 0,07 seconds)

Comment: Based on the getMessages, locations loaded successfully.  What is the underlying unit of the break/impedence values on the network dataset? On the dataset I've been using, the imdepence was kilometers, so "250" would be interpreted as "250 km" -- maybe try 0.25 instead?

Comment: This seems like a new question - please separate out into a new one based on the solve error, as loading locations is no longer causing an error.

Comment: Solved, see my initial post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the different tools in the Network Analysis toolbox can have different sublayer names, some of which are common (e.g. both Closest Facility and Service Area Analysis use Facilities, but they use them in different ways.)

If you want to see the list of sublayer names for your particular analysis, Example 3 on [Esri's documentation for Make Service Area Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/make-service-area-layer.htm) has the following:

`subLayerNames = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(outNALayer)`

For the Service Area Analysis, use "Facilities" as the sublayer when adding locations that you are trying to create service areas for (e.g. traveling FROM or TO). If needed, things like point barriers would probably also be added via the AddLocations tool.

All of the sublayers available in a test service area (created via ArcGIS Pro, which may have different syntax):
`{'Facilities': 'Facilities', 'Barriers': 'Point Barriers', 'SALines': 'Lines', 'PolylineBarriers': 'Line Barriers', 'SAPolygons': 'Polygons', 'PolygonBarriers': 'Polygon Barriers'}`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I however now get the error: arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 030024: Solve returned a failure. No edges were traversed. Failed to execute (Solve).I attached everything to the first post again.